# variable scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
    calValue: function (data) {
            var self = this;
            var values = data.values;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  if(data.condition == 0){
                    (function (values) {
                            for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                            }
                    })(values)
                    }
                    else{
                            //do sth else
                    }
            }
    }
```

my understanding is each funtion has its own context and the variable being declared inside it, will only be effetive inside. Like above code snippet, i expect the "i" variable inside the inner for-loop  won't impact the outer one "i" variable. However, the fact is it do affect.

Could someone please help explain? Thanks.

Comment: This is because you don't re-declare `i` in the second inner function, so it's using the `i` from the outer function, not its own internal copy.

Comment: thanks daniel. that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

With `var` declarations, scope is at the `function` level. Such declarations are interpreted as if they appeared at the very start of the enclosing function.

In modern JavaScript environments, the `let` declaration allows you to create variables scoped to local blocks of statements. (Also `const` for non-modifiable symbols.)

In your case, that inner `i` in the nested function just refers to that `i` declared externally. From inside a function, you can always "see" out, but you can't "see" in. That's how scope works.